# How to load a StringStream with UTF8 characters to a StringList in Android?

Tags: android, delphi, utf-8, get, indy10

I made a simple Indy HTTP GET function that works perfectly using Windows client and server, but when using the client in Android it stuck when trying to load the StringStream to a StringList because of the use of UTF8 characters.

Client (inside a thread):

```
var
ss:TStringStream;
st:TStringList;
begin
ss := TStringStream.Create('',TEncoding.UTF8);
IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; MAAU)';
IdHTTP1.Get('http://motoristaajudante.ddns.net:37009/-23.671373,-046.700072',ss);
ss.Position := 0;
st := TStringList.Create;
st.LoadFromStream(ss); // <<< Crash in this line on Android, on Windows works fine
end;
```

Server:

```
procedure TfrmMain.DownloadServer9CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; 
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo); // Indy HTTP Server
var
    Enviar:TStringList;
    EnvioStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
try
    Enviar := TStringList.Create;
    Enviar.Add('11111111111111111111111111111111111111 0006 Jardim São Caetano|Fique mais próximo'+' do conjunto de prédios do Jardim São Caetano para aumentar as chances de receber um chamado. Tente parar exatamente onde é apontado no mapa. ¬iMobby¬d19/09/2017 00:00:00  2359235923592359  0012  000  23590 ¬§');
    Enviar.Add('11111111111111111111111111111111111111 0006 Jardim São Caetano|Fique mais próximo'+' do conjunto de prédios do Jardim São Caetano para aumentar as chances de receber um chamado. Tente parar exatamente onde é apontado no mapa. ¬iMobby¬d19/09/2017 00:00:00  2359235923592359  0012  000  23590 ¬§');
    Enviar.Add('11111111111111111111111111111111111111 0006 Jardim São Caetano|Fique mais próximo'+' do conjunto de prédios do Jardim São Caetano para aumentar as chances de receber um chamado. Tente parar exatamente onde é apontado no mapa. ¬iMobby¬d19/09/2017 00:00:00  2359235923592359  0012  000  23590 ¬§');
    Enviar.Add('@');
    // if switching the above strings to only numbers and letters then the client loads the StringList normally on Android

    EnvioStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    Enviar.SaveToStream(EnvioStream);

    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := EnvioStream;
    AResponseInfo.WriteContent;
finally
    Enviar.Free;
    Enviar := nil;
    EnvioStream.Free;
    EnvioStream := nil;
end;
```

Although, if switching all the sent strings to only numbers and letters then the client loads the StringList normally on Android, if I put just one UTF8 char it crash. How to solve this?

Edit: the message is "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810909/mobile-application-error-when-loading-from-stream

My bad. it's duplicate, 

The solution is changing the following line: `Enviar.SaveToStream(EnvioStream,TEncoding.UTF8);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `TEncoding.UTF8` is being ignored in this situation.

`TStringStream` is a stream of bytes in D2009+.  The `TEncoding` you pass to its constructor is never used (the input string to the constructor is empty, and you don't use the `DataString` property at all).  So, this code is downloading raw bytes and then loading those bytes as-is into the `TStringList` using `TEncoding.Default` for parsing, which just *happens* to be UTF-8 on Android, but is not UTF-8 on Windows.  If the data is not actually UTF-8, decoding it as UTF-8 will fail.

If you know for a fact that the downloaded data is encoded in UTF-8, then you need to specify that explicitly when calling `LoadFromStream()`:

```
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  st: TStringList;
begin
  st := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      //...
      IdHTTP1.Get('http://motoristaajudante.ddns.net:37009/-23.671373,-046.700072', ms);
      ms.Position := 0;
      st.LoadFromStream(ms, TEncoding.UTF8); // <-- here
    finally
      ms.Free;
    end;
    // use st as needed... 
  finally
    st.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But, if you don't know whether the data is UTF-8 or not, you are better off letting `TIdHTTP` decode it for you, based on how the HTTP server describes its encoding:

```
var
  st: TStringList;
begin
  st := TStringList.Create;
  try
    //...
    st.Text := IdHTTP1.Get('http://motoristaajudante.ddns.net:37009/-23.671373,-046.700072');
    // use st as needed... 
  finally
    st.Free;
  end;
end;
```

On the server side, you should be doing something more like this instead to ensure the data is encoded in UTF-8:

```
procedure TfrmMain.DownloadServer9CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo); // Indy HTTP Server
var
  Enviar: TStringList;
  EnvioStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Enviar := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Enviar.Add('11111111111111111111111111111111111111 0006 Jardim São Caetano|Fique mais próximo'+' do conjunto de prédios do Jardim São Caetano para aumentar as chances de receber um chamado. Tente parar exatamente onde é apontado no mapa. ¬iMobby¬d19/09/2017 00:00:00 2359235923592359 0012 000 23590 ¬§');
    Enviar.Add('11111111111111111111111111111111111111 0006 Jardim São Caetano|Fique mais próximo'+' do conjunto de prédios do Jardim São Caetano para aumentar as chances de receber um chamado. Tente parar exatamente onde é apontado no mapa. ¬iMobby¬d19/09/2017 00:00:00 2359235923592359 0012 000 23590 ¬§');
    Enviar.Add('11111111111111111111111111111111111111 0006 Jardim São Caetano|Fique mais próximo'+' do conjunto de prédios do Jardim São Caetano para aumentar as chances de receber um chamado. Tente parar exatamente onde é apontado no mapa. ¬iMobby¬d19/09/2017 00:00:00 2359235923592359 0012 000 23590 ¬§');
    Enviar.Add('@');
    EnvioStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Enviar.SaveToStream(EnvioStream, TEncoding.UTF8); // <-- here
    except
      EnvioStream.Free;
      raise;
    end;
    // AResponseInfo.ContentStream takes ownership of the stream
    // and will free it when AResponseInfo is freed. TIdHTTPServer
    // will send the response automatically when this OnCommandGet
    // handler exits, so you don't need to call WriteContent()
    // manually... 
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := EnvioStream;
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/plain'; // <-- add this! 
    AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8'; // <-- add this! 
  finally
    Enviar.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy! It woked perfectly both client and server, even after hundreds of attempts on a poor 3G connection.

Comment: At least in Delphi Rio (I haven't tested it in other Delphis) the AEncoding argument present in the TStringStream constructor WORKS. In other words, by not using this argument, the DataString property behaves like a RawByteString, that is, characters that are encoded in UTF-8 do not appear in the final string. Instead, two characters are shown. When using TEncoding.UTF8, characters are correctly displayed in the final string. The DataString property, in this case, behaves like a "de facto" String or, more specifically, like a UTF8String